# Почему изображение не выравнивается по вертикали?

Tags: html, css, изображения, выравнивание

Есть блок с картинкой

```css
.service-image {
  display: table;
  min-height: 129px;
}

img {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="service-image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/80x64" width="80" height="64">
</div>
```

Почему он не выравнивается по вертикальному центру и как это исправить?

Comment: так как необходимо задавать не картинке выравнивание, а создать внутренний блок таблицы и задать ему display: table-cell;  vertical-align: middle;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В html5 нужно указывать что теги html и body занимают определенную высоту, иначе высота подбирается относительно размеров содержимого.

```css
html, body, .service-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.service-image {
  display: table;
}

.service-image>div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="service-image">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x64" width="80" height="64">
  </div>
</div>
```